# discord.py how to pass another command inside a command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Currently I can change setting using `?hoist yes`.

I want to make it if I want to change the settings I have to write `?settings [setting] [value]`. for example, `?settings hoist yes`

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def settings(self, ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(description="You can use `?[settings] [value]` to change a value of a specific setting. \nfor example, `?createroles yes`", color=0x850000)
    embed.set_author(name='ARB', icon_url='https://i.imgur.com/7ytdI2o.png')
    embed.add_field(name="Create Roles - `createroles`", value="Automatically create roles for games being played by members.", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Mention - `mention`", value="Allow anyone to @mention roles created by ARB.", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Hoist - `hoist`", value="Display roles created by ARB separately from online members.", inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="use prefix ? before each command.")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def hoist(self, ctx, value):
    embed=discord.Embed(color=0x850000)
    embed.add_field(name="hoist", value=f'has been set to `{value}`.', inline=False)
      
    if value.lower() == 'yes':
        self.stg_hoist = True
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    elif value.lower() == 'no':
        self.stg_hoist = False
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=0x850000).add_field(name="hoist", value=f'can not be set to `{value}`'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the discord.py docs (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#positional) you can have however many *positional* arguments you want. So just add some *positional* arguments.

```
@commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def settings(self, ctx, setting=None, value=None):
  if setting is None:
    # Whatever your settings was doing before, maybe with
    # updated help text to show new usage
  elif setting == "hoist":
    await self.hoist(ctx, value)
```

If that doesn't suit you, e.g. because not all settings have exactly one value, you can use *variable* number of arguments (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#variable) and check whether you have what you need based on the specific setting you're changing (e.g. like this: `len(args) >= 1 and args[0] == "hoist"`)

Comment: for `await hoist(ctx, value)` I'm getting `Undefined variable 'hoist'`. Do I have to make a hoist function inside settings function?

Comment: the same as you do any other functions... havent notice that you have self, so probably `self.hoist`